# Flutter: how to create Apple/google wallet card

Tags: flutter, wallet, passkit

Is there any way to create passes/cards for Apple wallet and google wallet? In swift this is done with passkit. How can I do it in Flutter!?

Note I want to had card like tickets, boarding pass, loyalty card. I am not looking after adding credit card or payment methods

Thanks[image]

Comment: if i get you right you mean in UX, am I right? or you mean technical part?

Comment: I would like to create a pass as per Apple guidelines. I have added a picture in the main question

Comment: I've been doing bunch of research right now, so far there's no such plugin

Comment: That's strange. We must be able to just add cards to apple wallet. there must be some way to access/edit pass.json file which is at the core of generating the apple wallet cards

Answer (score 0):

Actually now there is a [pass_flutter library](https://pub.dev/packages/pass_flutter) for that.

Update: in version 2.0.0, you can now save passes like so:

```
import 'package:pass_flutter/pass_flutter.dart';

PassFile passFile = await Pass().fetchPreviewFromUrl(url: 'https://link_to_pass/pass.pkpass');
passFile.save();
```

Comment: Can you create passes? It looks like it is only related to getting the list of passes, deleting, etc but not to create them

Comment: yeah, seems that's still not possible...