# Create Apple Wallet Pass Dynamically In Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, passkit, apple-wallet

I am looking to create a `Apple Wallet Pass in Flutter`. I was able to create a static pass in `.pkpass` format following instruction from [Apple's Wallet Official Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1).

Although, the original requirement is to create a dynamic pass which will be specific to logged in user. So, I want to **create pass dynamically using Pass Generator in Flutter**. We have `PassKitGenerator` for `iOS` using `swift` and also, for `react`.

Does anybody know, how can I generate pass dynamically in Flutter.

1. I checked, [Flutter packages for pass generator](https://pub.dev/packages?q=platform%3Aios%20pass%20generator) as well. Nothing found.
2. Also, looked into [this duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942987/flutter-how-to-create-apple-google-wallet-card).

Thanks

Comment: You should not create dynamic passes on the device. You should use a server to create the pass file.  Creating a pass requires access to private keys and a certificate passcode.  These should not be embedded in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That totally make sense. Can you recommend any link about how can I generate pass on server and sign it. Thanks